# postgres JOIN with left table null

Tags: postgresql, join, null

my query is:

```
SELECT main.group_id, s_ref.title, s_ref.username, main.m_per_group, main.pos, u.lang 
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, group_id, COUNT(user_id) AS m_per_group,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY group_id
            ORDER BY COUNT(group_id) DESC
            ) AS pos 
    FROM messages
    WHERE message_date > date_trunc('week', now())
    GROUP BY group_id, user_id
) AS main 
LEFT OUTER JOIN supergroups_ref AS s_ref
USING (group_id)
RIGHT JOIN users AS u
ON u.user_id = main.user_id
WHERE main.user_id = %s
ORDER BY m_per_group DESC
```

the problem is that when main returns 0 elements, i don't get neither the language of the user of the users JOIN but i get exactly `[]`

i instead would like to get `[(None, None, None, None, 'en')]` this is why i used a right join. How can i get the result i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this condition:

```
WHERE main.user_id = %s
```

To the main subquery:

```
WHERE message_date > date_trunc('week', now()) and main.user_id = %s
```

The way it is now it is turning an outer join into an inner join.